# How do you translate a Facebook tab name?

Tags: facebook

I've translated application tab names before by going here: http://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/browse.php?app=[YOURAPPID]

But I'm not seeing any entries available for localization. Is this a bug or am I looking in the wrong spot now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any localization you can do is now at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ under the "Localize" link item on the left